# Shortest way to integrate $\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for the shortest way to integrate $\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}dx$

All the other integration questions I've worked through in the same book section were pretty straightforward, whereas this one seems to take me through more steps than seems reasonable based on the other questions.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Various solutions here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1142684/42969,  here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/385274/42969, and here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053719/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1-x%7D%7Ddx%24)

Comment: I suggest that you present your solution if you are asking for a shorter one (so that nobody possibly wastes their time by giving a solution that you already know).

Comment: Mmm I've never heard about the Approacho search engine before but it looks very promising

Comment: Thank you, the Approacho link is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}dx
=-\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}d(1-x)
=-\sqrt{{x}(1-x)} +\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}d(\sqrt x)\\
 =-\sqrt{{x}(1-x)} -\cos^{-1}\sqrt x+C
$$

Answer (score 0):

The idea to compute such integral $\int f(x) d x$ is to produce a nice parametrization of the curve $y=f(x)$, say $y(t), x(t)$ so that the integral becomes $\int y(t) x'(t) dt$. Here  $y^2 (1-x)=x$ or $x(1+y^2)= y^2$ using $y$ as a parameter the integral is $\int y ({y^2\over 1+y^2})' dy$, then you can use standard methods (integration by part+ usual functins)

$\int y ({y^2\over 1+y^2})' dy= y ({y^2\over 1+y^2})+ \int {y^2\over 1+y^2} dy$

and $ \int {y^2\over 1+y^2} dy=   \int {1+y^2 -1\over 1+y^2} dy= y - \arctan (y) $

Answer (score 0):

$$u =\sqrt{1-x}$$
$$du = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}$$
$$-2\int\sqrt{1-u^2}du$$
Now just make a trig sub $u=\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to solve the problem by the substitution $x=\sin^2 \theta.$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^{2} \theta}{1-\sin ^{2} \theta}}(2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta) \\
&=\int 2 \sin ^{2} \theta d \theta \\
&=\int(1-\cos 2 \theta) d \theta \\
&=\theta-\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}+C \\
&=\sin ^{-1} \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x(1-x)}+C
\end{aligned}
$$